# Triggering supertab on dot (and also Tab)

Tags: vim, supertab

i'm looking for a way to trigger SuperTab when writing a . (dot) in insert mode. I came up with something like this:

```
inoremap <buffer> . .<C-x><C-o>
```

But this just triggers Omnicompletion and not SuperTab. I want it to trigger SuperTab so I have my SuperTab configuration (preselect first entry, autoclose preview window).
Also I still want my normal SuperTab binding (which is Tab).

This could probably be solved by simulating  a  keypress (while in insert mode), but I just cant get it working.

```
inoremap <buffer> . .<Tab>
```

Just inserts a literal tab.
Any hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inoremap` means exactly:

> **`:ino[remap] {lhs} {rhs}`**
>
> Map the key sequence `{lhs}` to `{rhs}` for the modes
>   where the map command applies. **Disallow** mapping of
>   `{rhs}`, to avoid nested and recursive mappings.

Have you tried:

```
:imap . .<tab>
```

?

Comment: Oh, alright. I should have looked into the different map methods. I didn't think they could influence that. Thanks!